# java gui pass .txt file values into multiple jLists

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Ok. So I need to make a java GUI swing application, and I'm trying to pass data from a txt file by column into 4 jLists.
 For example I have this row: "John apples golden 15" in my txt file,  and I need to put each word into 4 separate jLists. My code for the first list is below, now Im stuck at the

```
for (Object item : itemList) {
           ;
}
```

```
    try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dfata.txt"));
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
            String lineJustFetched = null;
            String[] attributes;

            while (true) {
                lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
                if (lineJustFetched == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    attributes = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                    Item item = new Item(attributes[0], attributes[1], attributes[2], attributes[3], attributes[4]);
                    itemList.add(item);
                }
            }

            buf.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Object item : itemList) {
           ;
        }
        jListItemType.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = {""};

            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            public String getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
```

```css
class Item {

    String id;
    String type;
    String model;
    String size;
    String color;

    public Item(String id,String type, String model,  String size, String color) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.model = model;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Now I'm stuck..."` -- stuck, in what way? Please tell any important details.

Comment: I dont know how to do the parsing from the file to the jList by using that for

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- I see no need for you to extend AbstractListModel. This appears to just add complexity to your program with no benefit.
- Instead why not use a `DefaultListModel<Item>` for your JList's model
- Change that for-each loop so that it loops through Items not Objects, and then add your Items into the DefaultListModel within that loop.
- Or better still, there's no need for your program to have the itemlist, and instead, fill your `DefaultListModel<Item>` directly where you now fill the itemList.
- To have the list display properly either give Item a `toString()` method or set the JList's renderer. To do the latter, simply extend DefaultListCellRenderer.

Please check out the following links:

- [DefaultListCellRenderer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html)
- [How to Use Lists Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

e.g.,

```
private DefaultListModel<Item> itemModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
private JList<Item> itemList = new JList<>(itemModel);
```

```
// elsewhere
lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
if (lineJustFetched == null) {
    break;
} else {
    attributes = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
    Item item = new Item(attributes[0], attributes[1], attributes[2], attributes[3], attributes[4]);
    itemModel.addElement(item);
}
```

For more on DefaultListCellRenderer, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22851382/522444).

Comment: @DanielVantas: Please see enclosed links. Also what specifically is ambiguous, what confuses you?

Comment: @DanielVantas: some code added. Note that I'm not your down-voter.